# How does dynamic arrays(std::vector) work in c++?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, c++17, c++14

According to what I heard std::vector stores data contiguously
and when you try to add or delete an element to it grow or shrink by allocating new memory and copies everything from the old memory to the new memory with the changes and deletes the old memory

in the code below I have a copy constructor
it says copied every time the class gets copied
it gave me 6 copied messages when I had 3 elements and which was fine
but when I added another element it gave me 7 messages

Isn't it supposed to give me 10?
And how to optimize that?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct Vertex
{
    int x, y, z;

    Vertex(int x, int y, int z) : x(x), y(y), z(z)
    {
    }

    Vertex(const Vertex &vetrex) : x(vetrex.x), y(vetrex.y), z(vetrex.z)
    {
        std::cout << "Copied" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Vertex> vertices;
    vertices.push_back({1, 2, 3});
    vertices.push_back({4, 5, 6});
    vertices.push_back({7, 8, 9});
    vertices.push_back({10, 11, 12});
}
```

Comment: Can you explain in more detail why you think it should be 10?

Comment: @NathanPierson 10 = 1+2+3+4. The reason you don't see 10 is that vectors use geometric growth rather than linear.

Comment: first copy for the first element from the main fun stack to the vector stack 2nd and 3rd because it will copy the first element and the 2nd element to the new allocation 4th, 5th, and 6th because it will do the same thing but for the 3 elements and then it should be coping 4 elements to the new memory

Comment: @SobhyRzk Okay, yes, that would be the case if whenever the vector was at capacity `N` and added a new element it only reserved room for `N+1` element. But as @RaymondChen points out the capacity growth is more than linear, so in fact it doesn't need to reallocate and copy at all for that fourth `push_back`. (The exact reallocation strategy is implementation-dependent.)

Comment: `vector` will use every trick the implementer thinks of and can prove works to reduce the amount of copying required. Sometimes you'll see it do really sneaky stuff like no copies at all because it noticed, one way or another, that it already had all the storage it needed.

Comment: You might want to add some output between the calls to `vertices.push_back()` so that we can see the number of copies per call, rather than just the total number of copies.

Answer (score 2):

> According to what I heard `std::vector` stores data contiguously and when you try to add or delete an element to it grow or shrink by allocating new memory and copies everything from the old memory to the new memory with the changes and deletes the old memory

`std::vector<T>` doesn't actually grow *every single time you add an element to it*. It has a notion of something called capacity (See [`std::vector<T>::capacity()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/capacity)).

The actual number that grows or shrinks every single time an element is added is the `std::vector<T>::size()` which is just a restricting boundary over the capacity. The capacity is what actually tells you how many elements have been allocated at the time.

Essentially, in most implementations, the capacity of a `std::vector<T>` grows by powers of 2. (There is a reason behind doing this and this is mostly related to performance.)

So, examine the capacity in each of the `push_back()` calls to see this:

```cpp
int main()
{
    std::vector<Vertex> vertices;
    std::cout << "Size: " << vertices.size() << std::endl;         // Size: 0
    std::cout << "Capacity: " << vertices.capacity() << std::endl; // Capacity: 0
    vertices.push_back({1, 2, 3});                                 // 1 copy 
    std::cout << "***" << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Size: " << vertices.size() << std::endl;         // Size: 1
    std::cout << "Capacity: " << vertices.capacity() << std::endl; // Capacity: 2^0 = 1
    vertices.push_back({4, 5, 6});                                 // 2 copies (due to reallocation)
    std::cout << "***" << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Size: " << vertices.size() << std::endl;         // Size: 2
    std::cout << "Capacity: " << vertices.capacity() << std::endl; // Capacity: 2^1 = 2
    vertices.push_back({7, 8, 9});                                 // 3 copies (due to reallocation)
    std::cout << "***" << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Size: " << vertices.size() << std::endl;         // Size: 3
    std::cout << "Capacity: " << vertices.capacity() << std::endl; // Capacity: 2^2 = 4
    vertices.push_back({10, 11, 12});                              // 1 copy
    std::cout << "***" << std::endl;
}
```

As you can see, in the fourth time you call `push_back()`, the capacity of `vertices` is `4` is and its size is `3` so it conveniently just does one copy and doesn't have to reallocate anything as there is already enough space.

> And how to optimize that?

If you already know how many elements are going to be added beforehand, you could call [`std::vector<T>::reserve()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) before any `push_back()` calls:

```
vertices.reserve(4);
```

This avoids any sort of reallocation and simply does 4 copies.

Answer (score 2):

Let's step through it:

```
std::vector<Vertex> vertices;
```

At this point, capacity is 0, size is 0.

```
vertices.push_back({1, 2, 3});
```

Vector allocates a buffer of size 1 to hold the element.
copy construct argument passed to `push_back` into vector [1/7 copies]

```
vertices.push_back({4, 5, 6});
```

vector capacity is 1, size is 1.  It is full, so to add a 2nd element it allocates a new buffer double in size (now 2).

- copy the existing element in vector into new memory [2/7 copies]
- copy construct argument passed to `push_back` into vector [3/7 copies]
- delete old buffer (and destroy objects in it)

then:

```
vertices.push_back({7, 8, 9});
```

vector capacity is 2, size is 2.  Again it is again full and doubles its buffer size by allocating a buffer of size 4.

- copy 2 elements from old allocation to new allocation [(4&5)/7 copies]
- copy argument passed to `push_back` into vector [6/7] copies
- delete old buffer (and destroy objects in it)

then:

```
vertices.push_back({10, 11, 12});
```

Vector capacity is 4, size is 3.  It has room for the new element without resizing.

- copy argument passed to `push_back` into vector [7/7] copies

Note, the vector "doubling" is common but not required by the standard.  Implementations could resize to other amounts, so do not depend on anticipating the reallocation size.

Also, to reduce the number of reallocations, you can reserve size in advance of all the insertions.  In that case it's FAR more efficient:

```
std::vector<Vertex> vertices;
vertices.reserve(4);
```

If you add the call to reserve space for 4 elements at the beginning, then there are only 4 copies--one per element added into the vector.